# How to pass URL to custom function

Tags: twig, grav

I want to send url the website from Twig template to plugin (I create One plugin) in grav but when I get the value of url is "null". here is code twig

```
{% extends 'partials/base.html.twig' %}

{% block content %}

    {% set fullUrl = page.url(true)|e %}
        {% set parsedUrl = fullUrl|parse_url %}
        {% set url = parsedUrl.host %} 

    {{ url }}

    {% set data = getdata(url) %}
```

and for plugin

```
public function getFunctions(): array
    {
        return [
            new \Twig_SimpleFunction('getdata', [$this, 'exampleFunction'])
        ];
    }

    public function exampleFunction($url)
    {
        // Extract host from URL
        $host = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_HOST);
        if ($host === null) {
            echo 'Invalid URL';
        }
        dump($host);
```

I am try to get the url in my plugin but I get NULL of value the $url

Comment: Please separate snippets according to origin and format properly.

Comment: "*I get the value of url is "null"*" - Your question is bit unclear, can you clarify where this occurs? Furthermore why are you creating the function `exampleFunction` if the filter `parse_url` is available and (apparently) does the same thing that `exampleFunction` will do?

Comment: Have a look at the following snippet, because this is what your current code is doing - [demo](https://ideone.com/f8DaO7)

Comment: Yeah, but still "null" when I acces directly  in function exampleFunction($url) ` $host = $url`

Comment: How did you test this? Did you do a `dump($url)` in the function `exampleFunction`?

Comment: I want just get the value of url  from twig template and be accessible in function  exampleFunction($url)

Comment: Yeah I use dum($url)

Comment: Then please update the question with where and how you've verified this

Comment: Variable `url` in your Twig contains the host of `parsedUrl`, which you then pass into function `getData(url)`. Function `parse_url($url)` in PHP returns `null` when `$url` contains only a host string and not a Url. You should use  `getData(fullUrl)`.